# Images from a JS for-loop do not load up on HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of images in JS that I need to contain in HTML.  This is my array and the JS code:

```
// Data for the "HTML Images" Page

var images = [
    {caption: "Red Slate Mountain", alt: "Mountain", url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Red_Slate_Mountain_1.jpg/320px-Red_Slate_Mountain_1.jpg"},
    {caption: "St. Petersburg River", alt: "River", url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Saint-petersburg-river-march-24-2016.jpg/320px-Saint-petersburg-river-march-24-2016.jpg"},
    {caption: "Lybian Desert", alt: "Desert", url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/99/Libyan_Desert_-_2006.jpg/320px-Libyan_Desert_-_2006.jpg"},
    {caption: "Azerbaijan Forest", alt: "Forest", url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Azerbaijan_forest_3.JPG/320px-Azerbaijan_forest_3.JPG"},
    {caption: "Indonesian Jungle", alt: "Jungle", url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f5/Indonesian_jungle3%2C_Zoo_Prague.jpg/320px-Indonesian_jungle3%2C_Zoo_Prague.jpg"}
];

window.onload = function(){
    var figure = "<figure>";
    for(var i = 0; i <= images.length; i++){
        figure += '<img src="'+ images[i].url + '" ' + 'alt="' + images[i].alt + '">' 
        + '<figcaption>' + images[i].caption + "</figcaption>"   
    }figure += "</figure>";

    var myContainer = document.querySelector("#image").innerHTML = figure;
}
```

and this is the HTML container:

```
<section class="main center">

            <h2>HTML Images</h2>
            <a href="https://ict.senecacollege.ca/" target="_blank">
                <img src="assignment3/img/ict.png">
            </a>
            <h2>Scenes</h2>
            <div id="image"></div>

    </section>
```

But the page is blank.  I am assuming that the issue is my concatenation but I couldn't find an error with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 5 items in the array 'images'. Your loop starts at 0 and goes up until and including 5, which is 6 iterations.

you want `i < images.length`

you are currently accessing .url of `undefined` (the default value for an index that does not exist)

Comment: Where am I accessing the .url of undefined?

Comment: Thanks man.  I removed my mistake.  I've accepted your answer and if you think that my question was well asked, could you give me an upvote?

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating once more than necessary due to the equals sign and it is causing an error. an array of length 6 has its last element at 5.

Comment: Also as someone has mentioned the console is very helpful. If you code stops working but no indication of breakage is shown on the screen, often an error can be found in the console. Use f12 to get to developer mode on most browsers

Answer (score 1):

You could also [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array to a string:

```
const figure = images.reduce(
  (all,image)=>
    all + '<img src="'+ image.url + '" ' + 'alt="' + image.alt + '">' 
    + '<figcaption>' + image.caption + "</figcaption>",
  "<figure>"//initial value
) + "</figure>";
```